# How to mail link from mobile Safari to an Exchange address book entry?

Tags: email, mobile-safari, exchange

When selecting Mail Link to this Page from mobile Safari, no Exchange address groups are available when attempting to insert a recipient ("Choose a contact to mail").

Also, Outlook Personal Contacts are listed as part of the displayed All Contacts view, but not the Global Address List group. Contrast this with the mail-link case with Photos (native app) or Mercury browser.

Thank you.

ATT iPhone 4, iPad 1, iOS 5.0.1, 3G, WiFi

Answer (score 1):

Outlook Personal Contacts do show in the Global Address List because the global contacts are controlled by the domain administrator. You'll have to browse All Contacts for the contacts you wish to share the page with.

Comment: Thanks, but the Global Address List is not shown in the Groups list view, nor is it queried from the All Contacts view. Try selecting an Exchange address group in a compose from Safari vs the same case using Photos or Mercury or Maps.